# CRM 2011 - Quickest Lookup of Account by Email Address Domain

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm

I'm looking for the quickest way to return a set of accounts that have contacts with email addresses that match a domain name in CRM 2011. I'm using early-bound entities. I'm thinking a Linq query would be easiest, fastest but not sure where to start. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @jacobappleton start, I was getting an error "Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method."

The issue, which I do not completely understand, is with this line:

```
where c.EMailAddress1.Substring(c.EMailAddress1.IndexOf('@')) == email.Substring(email.IndexOf('@')
```

While less accurate, I've swapped that for the following instead. Defining domain before the query.

```
where c.EMailAddress1.Contains(domain)
```

End Result:

```
public Account GetAccount(string email)
{
    var context = new ServiceContext(_service);
    var domain = email.Substring(email.IndexOf('@'));
    var contacts = from c in context.ContactSet
                   where c.EMailAddress1.Contains(domain)
                   where c.StateCode == ContactState.Active
                   where c.ParentCustomerId != null
                   select c;

    return RetrieveEntity(Account.EntityLogicalName, contacts.First<Contact>().ParentCustomerId.Id, new ColumnSet(true)).ToEntity<Account>();
}
```

**Related,** how do I check the count of records returned. *contacts.Any()* is not supported?

Comment: Try `contacts.Count()` this should give you the number of contacts returned.

Answer (score 2):

You would need something like this:

```
var query = (
    from c in ctx.contacts
    where c.emailaddress1.Substring(c.emailaddress1.IndexOf('@')) == "@domain.com"
    && c.statuscode == 0
    select c);
```

This is assuming you already have created your early binding classes and have set up a data context.

This link gives quite a bit of info on getting you to the point you need to actually run the Linq code above: http://sandrinodimattia.net/blog/post/Early-binding-tips-and-tricks-for-Dynamics-CRM-2011.aspx

Hope that helps.

Comment: Instead of using .Substring, would it not be easier / more efficient to use .EndsWith? As in `where c.emailaddress1.EndsWith("@domain.com")`?

Comment: Efficiency-wise I'd say they're quite similar: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith%28v=vs.71%29.aspx but I'll admit `EndsWith` is slightly easier.